# Provider-Hosted App in Azure

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Can an Azure system be used as a on-premise system. I am doing Provider-hosted apps in SharePoint 2013. Can the red box in the diagram be a Azure system? [image: Can the red box in the diagram be Azure]

Answer (score 0):

No.  Windows Azure does not work on premise.  Microsoft was working on an Azure appliance at one point for very large customers, but I believe it was abandoned.

You could look at a deployment automation tool like Octopus (http://octopusdeploy.com/).

Comment: Okay thank you, what about the question involving red box. Is that no as well?